# Citrix Go Daddy SSL Cert Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: ssl, citrix, icaclient

I have installed Citrix following the instructions in this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

including adding more SSL certificates:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
```

The site I am trying to reach is hosted by GoDaddy and I get an SSL ERROR 61.

Has anyone successfully solved this issue and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error 61 might have more reasons. I have solved the problem I had.

I have followed the same instructions, specifically point 1. leading to

https://mark911.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/how-to-install-citrix-receiver-icaclient-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit-tested-and-working-using-mozilla-firefox/

This installs version 13.0 of the icaclient, which seem to be too old. The actual issue was that our server uses type SHA-2 HASH in SSL certificate which is not supported by icaclient 13.0, but it is by 13.3, so after upgrading with deb file with 64bit icaclient 13.3 from citrix pages, it started to work.

See my answer to

[Citrix Error "You have not trusted certificate"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666064/citrix-error-you-have-not-trusted-certificate)

This might be duplicate of question above.